# why is my normal map pink?

Tags: normals, texture-baking, normal-map

My normal maps keep coming out pink like this. ive tried several diff frontal and rear ray distances to no avail:
[image]

here are my uvs: [image]

the high poly model: [image]

Comment: Maybe increase the Bake Distance value a bit? Or please share your fil so that we can try?